# How to remove make new folder FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: c#, directory, folderbrowserdialog

Hi I'm using  FolderBrowserDialog with wpf in visual studio 2013 but i want remove the button make new folder because in my application is meaningless, I see this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14454/Extended-Folder-Browser that disable this button but I would remove this button

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a property which allows you to hide it.

```
var x = new FolderBrowserDialog();
x.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
```

Check out the class documentation here: [FolderBrowserDialog Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog)